# Parsing current uri to get the current route params inside a partial. How to avoid?

Tags: php, symfony, twig, silex

To render TOC (categories tree) inside the **base.twig** view I call the `render()` function passing it the corresponding action url:

```
{% block sidebar %}

    {{ render(url('toc_documents_categories')) }}    

{% endblock %}
```

The matching partial view for the `'/toc/documents'` action (**_toc.documents_categories.twig**) is defined as follows:

```
{% set category_id = (current_uri|split('/'))[4] %}

{% macro recursiveCategory(category, active_category_id) %}

    <li>

        {% if category.children|length %}

            <a><span class="icon icon-plus"></span>{{ category.name_displayed }}</a>

        {% else %}

            {% set active_class = active_category_id == category.id ? 'active' %}
            {% set url = app.url_generator.generate('documents_by_category', {category_id: category.id}) %}

            <a href="{{ url }}" class="{{ active_class }}">
                {{ category.name_displayed }}
            </a>

        {% endif %}

        {% if category.children|length %}
            <ul>
                {% for child in category.children %}
                    {{ _self.recursiveCategory(child, active_category_id) }}
                {% endfor %}
            </ul>
        {% endif %}
    </li>
{% endmacro %}

{% if categories %}
    <div id="categories">
        <ul>
            {% for category in categories %}
                {{ _self.recursiveCategory(category, category_id) }}
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    </div>
{% endif %}
```

As you can see I'm extracting current category's id by parsing current url. This is preceded by setting the **current_uri** global:

```
$app->before(function(Request $request) use ($app) {
    $app['twig']->addGlobal('current_uri', $request->getRequestUri());
});
```

Accessing the route information (`global.request.attributes.get('_route')`) inside the partial view shows the corresponding **subrequest** route name and not the actual request route name (**master request**).

Is there a way to avoid manually parsing the current uri and to get the current request route params inside the partial view?

Comment: Why not pass the category_id in the `render` function? `base.twig` will always be the topmost request.

Comment: @keyboardSmasher Thank you very much, I think I understood what you meant!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the solution.

`render()` issues a **subrequest**, so you have to use the **master request** context:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request

$app->get('/documents_categories', function(Request $request) use($app) {

    $master_request = $app['request_stack']->getMasterRequest();
    $current_route = $master_request->get('_route');
    $active_category_id = null; 

    if($current_route === 'documents_by_category') {
        $active_category_id = $master_request->get('_route_params')['category_id']; 
    }

    // ... do things: parse toc tree ...

    return $app['twig']->render('_toc.documents.categories.twig', array(
        "categories" => $toc_tree,
        "active_category_id" => $active_category_id
    ));

})->bind('toc_documents_categories');
```

Then inside the partial view you have to only reference the passed **active_category_id** parameter:

```
{% if categories %}
    <div id="categories">
        <ul>
            {% for category in categories %}
                {{ _self.recursiveCategory(category, active_category_id) }}
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    </div>
{% endif %}
```

Thanks to @keyboardSmasher for 'Why not pass the category_id in the render function' comment. Yet I'm not sure if I did it the way he assumed.